# How to connect to mssql with php?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

Thing i got all the addons working, some unofficial pdo driver for php(5.6)

This is my php;

```
<?php
$head =  $_POST['title'];
$bread = $_POST['html'];
$author = $_POST['selectlist1'];
$postdate = date('y-m-d h:i:s',time());
$cat = $_POST['selectlist2'];
$serverName = 'SERVER\SQLEXPRESS';
$db = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=$serverName;Database=blog', 'sa', '******');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO dbo.blog_posts (blog_title, blog_post, blog_author, blog_date, blog_category) VALUES (:head, :bread, :author, :postdate, :cat)';

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array(':head'=>$head, ':bread'=>$bread, ':author'=>$author, ':postdate'=>$postdate, ':cat'=>$cat ) );

?>
```

And i get the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. ' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\post.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\post.php(9): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=$...', 'sa', '*****') #1 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\post.php on line 9

i have enabled named pipes etc i have no more ideas what im doing wrong... i have googled several hours...
instead of $serverName i have tried with localhost,127.0.0.1 etcetc but i cant get it working!

after some more digging around i found out that Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53] is some kind of network problem, dunno what problem tho...

Oke i think im something on the way, now i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.' in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\post.php:15 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\post.php(15): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blog\post.php on line 15

Comment: Is your PHP code on a Windows machine?

Comment: @JeroenFlamman yes sir

Comment: Oops that was an unnecessary question - the error clearly points that out 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot'

Comment: im running my own iis server with both mysql and mssql, i want to mixture abit with both db handlers

Comment: I have more experience with mssql connections from a Linux machine - afraid I won't be of much help here..

Comment: Are you running your code on the same machine that is running the sql server instance? If not, have you tried connecting using TCP/IP?

Comment: @hamish yes the server is running both iis and the mssql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have done so many changes to everything and nothing tbh, but now it finally works, at the end my code looks like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$head =  $_POST['title'];
$bread = $_POST['html'];
$author = $_POST['selectlist1'];
$postdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$cat = $_POST['selectlist2'];
$db = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=localhost;Database=blog', '****', '******');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO dbo.blog_posts (blog_title, blog_post, blog_author, blog_date, blog_category) VALUES (:head, :bread, :author, :postdate, :cat)';

$query = $db->prepare( $sql );
$query->execute( array(':head'=>$head, ':bread'=>$bread, ':author'=>$author, ':postdate'=>$postdate, ':cat'=>$cat ) );

?>
```

So basically the thing ive tried all along did work, i have changed some ownership thingys in ms sql server management studio etc, i think that did the thing for me!